# Django form.ModelMultipleChoiceField label needed for each checkbox generated

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

please I want the name given to each generated checkbox(in the html) to have different names base on the "title" field in the Category Model. The html output is giving the same label(name) to each checkbox produced.

Here is my forms.py

class ProductFilterForm(forms.Form):

```
category_id = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    label='Categories',
    queryset=Category.objects.all(), 
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, 
    required=False)
```

as you can see, this html is generated. but i want each to have the name base on category title. "Category object is displayed but that is not what I want"

```
</label> <div class="controls "> <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" name="category_id" id="id_category_id_1" value="1" >Category object
        </label> <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" name="category_id" id="id_category_id_2" value="2" >Category object
        </label> <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" name="category_id" id="id_category_id_3" value="3" >Category object
        </label> <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" name="category_id" id="id_category_id_4" value="4" >Category object
        </label> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_max_price" class="form-group"> <label for="id_max_price" class="control-label ">
```

This is the model.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)
        default = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='default_category', null=True, blank=True)


        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title 
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Please this is the output**

```
            Categories
        </label> <div class="controls "> <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" name="category_id" id="id_category_id_1" value="1" >Category object
    </label> <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" name="category_id" id="id_category_id_2" value="2" >Category object
    </label> <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" name="category_id" id="id_category_id_3" value="3" >Category object
    </label> <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" name="category_id" id="id_category_id_4" value="4" >Category object
    </label> </div>
```

I want the ** Category object**  to be replaced with each Category title in from the model.

**I HAVE BEEN SUFFERING TO GET THIS FIXED FOR THE PAST NUMBER OF DAYS.** **I think i only need to specify label in the forms.py but i don't know how to do so.**
Each checkboxes produced by the form is Named "CATEGORY OBJECT".
I want them to be named the **title field** in the **Category Model**

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly, defining **str** function in model class should help.

```
class Category(models.Model):
  ...

  def __str__():
    return Category.name
```

P.S.: I don't have enough population to comment your question. If it doesn't work for you, please let me know.

Comment: return self.name :)

Comment: I already have a Category class of such                                                       class Category(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
 slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
 description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
 active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
 timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

 def __unicode__(self):
  return self.title

Comment: Can u try '__str__' function instead of '__unicode__' ?